# Exponential series is cosh(x), how to show using summation?

Tags: real-analysis, summation, power-series, exponential-function, exponential-sum

I want to show that $$\cosh(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ‎\frac{(x)^{2n}‎}{(2n)!}‎
$$

I know that $cosh(x) = \frac{exp(x)+exp(-x)}{2}$ but i cant seem to get there from the original series. I know that $$ exp(x) ‎=‎ ‎‎\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ‎\frac{(x)^{n}‎}{(n)!}$$

and i split up the $x^{2n}$ into $x^n x^n$ but i can't seem to get the negative exp or simplify the (2n)!. 
I basically want to show that the series is cosh(x).

Comment: Actually $\cosh(x)=(e^x+e^{-x})/2.$ (With the minus that's $\sinh(x).$

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to play around with the Taylor Series terms of $e^x$. $$\cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2} \\ = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}}{2}$$ Now break the sums apart further into their even and odd terms, cancel the odd ones, group the even ones and see what is left. For example, you can write the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i$ as $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty i= \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2i + \sum_{i=1}^\infty (2i-1)$$

Comment: i find when i split the second sum  in the end :

Comment: sum x^n/n! + sum(x)^2n/(2n)! + sum(-x)^2n+1/(2n+1)!, then do i cancel the first and third terms out? what gives me the right to do that? although that would give the correct answer

Comment: @user135688: For $e^x$, the generic even term is $\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ and the generic odd term is $\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$. For $e^{-x}$, the generic even term is $\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ (note that the minus sign is gone because of the even exponent) and the generic odd term is $-\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$ (note that the minus sign remains because of the odd exponent). I am alluding to the facts that $(-x)^{2k}=(-1)^{2k}x^{2k}=x^{2k}$ and $(-x)^{2k+1}=(-1)^{2k+1}x^{2k+1}=-x^{2k+1}$.

Comment: @user135688 MPW is right; you should find that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$